# Tuples optimization challenge

Tags: performance-tuning, probability-or-statistics, combinatorics, histograms

Consider a function that for a given integer $0\le n <256$ computes the number of leading zeros in its binary representation.

```
LeadingZeros[x_] := LengthWhile[IntegerDigits[x, 2, 8], # == 0 &]
```

The following histogram can be easily plotted

```
Histogram[
LeadingZeros[#] & /@ (Min @@@ 
Tuples[ Range[0, 255], 2]), Automatic, "Probability"]
```

[image]

However, my MA crashes for the following

```
Histogram[LeadingZeros[#] & /@ (Min @@@ Tuples[Range[0, 255], 4])]
```

Can you optimize the code to be able to do this calculation.

I actually would like to perform a series of such calculations for $k=2, 4, 8, 16, \ldots$

```
Histogram[LeadingZeros[#] & /@ (Min @@@ Tuples[Range[0, 255], k])]
```

I suppose that for larger values of $k$ it is infeasible, and some randomized algorithm can be used. But I am also curious if the brute force approach can  be pushed further.

Comment: `n = 8`; `LeadingZeros[x_, n_] := LengthWhile[IntegerDigits[x, 2, n], # == 0 &]` ; `Table[{i, IntegerDigits[i, 2, n], LeadingZeros[i, n], 
   If[i == 0, n, n - Floor[Log2[i] + 1]]}, {i, 0, 2^n - 1}] // Grid`

Comment: @Syed I did not get. Can you reproduce my histogram with your code?

Comment: No, I am suggesting that leading zeros can be found without counting.

Comment: There are two things here. First, the error that you're seeing is not because of any performance problem with your LeadingZeros function. It's due to trying to create an enormous list with `Tuples[Range[0, 255], 4]`. Second, as Syed pointed out, you don't need to construct the digit sequence and then count the leading zeros (that you had to create with padding). So your implementation does seem likely to be inefficient compared to just directly computing what you're after like Syed demonstrated.

Comment: `lz[x_, n_] := If[x == 0, n, n - Floor[Log2[x] + 1]]` and `Histogram[
 lz[#, 8] & /@ (Min @@@ 
    Tuples[Range[0, 255], 2]), Automatic, "Probability"]` gives the histogram in the OP.

Comment: I should clarify. The "fix" is to avoid constructing the huge table first only to then start mapping stuff over it. You could instead build the result imperatively. You could use your version of LeadingZeros to do this, but when you get to where performance with that method is too slow, switch to what Syed demonstrated and see what improvement you get.

Comment: @lericr I know that tuples is a problem, therefore the title.

Comment: I would probably approach the question through probabilities instead of creating four billion tuples...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't use brute force, instead compute probabilities for each amount of leading zero bits in `OrderDistribution` for the smallest entry of `k` `DiscreteUniformDistribution`s:

```
With[{k = 2},
  Table[
   Probability[2^(7 - n + 1) > a >= Floor[2^(7 - n)], 
     Distributed[a, 
      OrderDistribution[{DiscreteUniformDistribution[{0, 255}], k}, 1]]]
    // Labeled[#, n] &,
   {n, 0, 8}]] // BarChart
```

[image]

This also works for larger `k` such as 4:

[image]

You can also derive a symbolic form of the probability:

```
Probability[
  2^(7 - n + 1) > a >= Floor[2^(7 - n)], 
  Distributed[a, 
   OrderDistribution[{DiscreteUniformDistribution[{0, 255}], k}, 1]]] //
 FullSimplify[#,
   Element[n, Integers] && Element[k, Integers] && 0 <= n <= 8 && k >= 1] &

(* -Piecewise[{{1 - (1 - Floor[2^(7 - n)]/256)^k, 1 <= Floor[2^(7 - n)]}}, 0] + 
 Piecewise[{{1, 2^n <= 1}, {1 - (1 - 2^(-n))^k, Inequality[1, LessEqual, 2^(8 - n), Less, 256]}}, 0] *)
```

**EDIT**:

You can also use `Histogram` instead of `BarChart` by converting probabilities into `WeightedData`:

```
With[{k = 2},
  Table[
   {n,
    Probability[2^(7 - n + 1) > a >= Floor[2^(7 - n)],
     Distributed[a, 
      OrderDistribution[{DiscreteUniformDistribution[{0, 255}], k}, 1]]]},
   {n, 0, 8}]] // Histogram[WeightedData @@ Transpose@#, {1}, "Probability"] &
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, I had not hope it can be done analytically. Amazing!